# How to print matching data from an array in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need check is today someone's birthday & print all the filtered names in react component one by one.

Ex : Happy Birthday Lakshan Test!

```
    const birthdays = [{
          name: "Bob Marley",
          birthmonth: 6,
          birthdate: 13
        },
          {
            name: "Lakshan Test",
            birthmonth: 6,
            birthdate: 13
          },
          {
            name: "Peter Pan",
            birthmonth: 7,
            birthdate: 4
          },
        ];
    
        const today = new Date();
    
    
        birthdays.find((it) => {
          if (it.birthdate === today.getDate() && it.birthmonth === today.getMonth()) {
            alert("Happy Birthday!" + it.name);
            
          } else {
            alert("Have a nice day!);
          }
        })
```

Comment: What is the output you expected and what is the output you got?

Comment: I expect today birthday list matching today date and list out them in react component. Sorry I am new to react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter` method to create array of people whose birthday is today. Then `map` that array with a child component with passing props:

```
// birthdayPeople is your filtered array
birthdayPeople.map((person) => {
  <YourComponent person={person} />
}) 

const YourComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <p>Happy Birthday {props.person.name}!</p>
  )
}
```

or you can directly print them in your parent component without a child component.

```
// birthdayPeople is your filtered array
   birthdayPeople.map((person) => {
     <p>Happy Birthday {person.name}!</p>
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const birthdays = [
    {
      name: "Bob Marley",
      birthmonth: 6,
      birthdate: 13,
    },
    {
      name: "Lakshan Test",
      birthmonth: 7,
      birthdate: 13,
    },
    {
      name: "Peter Pan",
      birthmonth: 8,
      birthdate: 13,
    },
  ];

  const todayDate = new Date().getDate();
  const todayMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1; // month start from 0 jan to 11 dec

  const checkBirthday = () => {
    const value = birthdays.filter(
      (date) => date.birthmonth === todayMonth && date.birthdate === todayDate
    );

    if (value?.length > 0) {
      return alert(`Happy Birthday ${value[0].name}`);
    } else {
      return alert("Have a nice day!");
    }
  };

checkBirthday();
```